# How to script the Rolling Shutter?

Tags: python, camera, effects

I am trying to script the motion blur Rolling Shutter, but I can't find any API to change it to "Top-Bottom" through the searching bar. Is there a way to set the variable "Rolling shutter"? Thank you in advance!

[image: RS]

[image: Search]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.html#bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.rolling_shutter_type). To access the property use:

```
bpy.context.scene.cycles.rolling_shutter_type = 'TOP'
```

For some reason it doesn't update immediately even by using `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`. But it does update when you select something. So you could do a workaround and select a random object after setting the *rolling_shutter_type*:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.cycles.rolling_shutter_type = 'TOP'
bpy.data.objects[0].select_set(True) #workaround to update rolling_shutter_type
```

[image]